# Apache 2.4 + PHP-FPM ProxyPassMatch htaccess processed but ignored after "internal redirect"

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've setup an Ubuntu Server 14.04.1 with Apache 2.4 and PHP5-FPM 5.5.9. I've configured Apache, to use proxy_fcgi together with ProxyPassMatch:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/$1
```

This is working as expected: I visit the page, content is rendered, everything looks super.

Now I add some content and a .htaccess, which should hide a subfolder (Yii2 /web folder):

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [L]
```

This should do the job - but it does not. So, I've enabled debug logging:

```
[Mon Dec 08 10:49:57.414781 2014] [authz_core:debug] [pid 21794] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 172.31.51.30:54313] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Mon Dec 08 10:49:57.415581 2014] [authz_core:debug] [pid 21794] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 172.31.51.30:54313] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Mon Dec 08 10:49:57.415761 2014] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 21794] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 172.31.51.30:54313] 172.31.51.30 - - [my.url/sid#7f4b93b491a0][rid#7f4b93a8c0a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/my.url/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/my.url/ ->
[Mon Dec 08 10:49:57.415898 2014] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 21794] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 172.31.51.30:54313] 172.31.51.30 - - [my.url/sid#7f4b93b491a0][rid#7f4b93a8c0a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/my.url/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri ''
[Mon Dec 08 10:49:57.416062 2014] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 21794] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 172.31.51.30:54313] 172.31.51.30 - - [my.url/sid#7f4b93b491a0][rid#7f4b93a8c0a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/my.url/] RewriteCond: input='/' pattern='!^public' => matched
[Mon Dec 08 10:49:57.416170 2014] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 21794] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 172.31.51.30:54313] 172.31.51.30 - - [my.url/sid#7f4b93b491a0][rid#7f4b93a8c0a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/my.url/] rewrite '' -> 'web/'
[Mon Dec 08 10:49:57.416309 2014] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 21794] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 172.31.51.30:54313] 172.31.51.30 - - [my.url/sid#7f4b93b491a0][rid#7f4b93a8c0a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/my.url/] add per-dir prefix: web/ -> /var/www/my.url/web/
[Mon Dec 08 10:49:57.416430 2014] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 21794] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 172.31.51.30:54313] 172.31.51.30 - - [my.url/sid#7f4b93b491a0][rid#7f4b93a8c0a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/my.url/] strip document_root prefix: /var/www/my.url/web/ -> /web/
[Mon Dec 08 10:49:57.416548 2014] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 21794] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 172.31.51.30:54313] 172.31.51.30 - - [my.url/sid#7f4b93b491a0][rid#7f4b93a8c0a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/my.url/] internal redirect with /web/ [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[Mon Dec 08 10:49:57.416730 2014] [authz_core:debug] [pid 21794] mod_authz_core.c(828): [client 172.31.51.30:54313] AH01628: authorization result: granted (no directives)
[Mon Dec 08 10:49:57.416905 2014] [proxy_fcgi:debug] [pid 21794] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(73): [client 172.31.51.30:54313] AH01060: set r->filename to proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/my.url/index.php
[Mon Dec 08 10:49:57.417040 2014] [proxy:debug] [pid 21794] mod_proxy.c(1104): [client 172.31.51.30:54313] AH01143: Running scheme fcgi handler (attempt 0)
[Mon Dec 08 10:49:57.417125 2014] [proxy_fcgi:debug] [pid 21794] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(764): [client 172.31.51.30:54313] AH01076: url: fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/my.url/index.php proxyname: (null) proxyport: 0
[Mon Dec 08 10:49:57.417203 2014] [proxy_fcgi:debug] [pid 21794] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(774): [client 172.31.51.30:54313] AH01078: serving URL //127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/my.url/index.php
[Mon Dec 08 10:49:57.417254 2014] [proxy:debug] [pid 21794] proxy_util.c(2020): AH00942: FCGI: has acquired connection for (*)
[Mon Dec 08 10:49:57.417300 2014] [proxy:debug] [pid 21794] proxy_util.c(2072): [client 172.31.51.30:54313] AH00944: connecting //127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/my.url/index.php to 127.0.0.1:9000
[Mon Dec 08 10:49:57.417542 2014] [proxy:debug] [pid 21794] proxy_util.c(2206): [client 172.31.51.30:54313] AH00947: connected /var/www/my.url/index.php to 127.0.0.1:9000
[Mon Dec 08 10:49:57.419240 2014] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 21794] [client 172.31.51.30:54313] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Mon Dec 08 10:49:57.419438 2014] [proxy:debug] [pid 21794] proxy_util.c(2035): AH00943: FCGI: has released connection for (*)
[Mon Dec 08 10:49:57.488883 2014] [authz_core:debug] [pid 21794] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 172.31.51.30:54313] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Mon Dec 08 10:49:57.489025 2014] [authz_core:debug] [pid 21794] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 172.31.51.30:54313] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Mon Dec 08 10:49:57.489334 2014] [core:info] [pid 21794] [client 172.31.51.30:54313] AH00128: File does not exist: /var/www/my.url/favicon.ico
[Mon Dec 08 10:49:57.682546 2014] [proxy:debug] [pid 21831] proxy_util.c(1694): AH00925: initializing worker fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/my.url/$1 shared
[Mon Dec 08 10:49:57.682753 2014] [proxy:debug] [pid 21831] proxy_util.c(1734): AH00927: initializing worker fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/my.url/$1 local
[Mon Dec 08 10:49:57.682819 2014] [proxy:debug] [pid 21831] proxy_util.c(1785): AH00931: initialized single connection worker in child 21831 for (127.0.0.1)
```

Especially this part looks interesting:

```
strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/my.url/ ->
applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri ''
RewriteCond: input='/' pattern='!^public' => matched
rewrite '' -> 'web/'
add per-dir prefix: web/ -> /var/www/my.url/web/
strip document_root prefix: /var/www/my.url/web/ -> /web/
internal redirect with /web/ [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

So, the rewrite seems to work, but what is going on after INTERNAL REDIRECT? Why is this rewrite ignored by ProxyPassmatch? Did I missed something?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** The VHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName      my.url
    ServerAdmin     me@myurl
    DocumentRoot        "/var/www/my.url"
    LogLevel        DEBUG rewrite:trace8
    ErrorLog        ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/my.url.error.log
    CustomLog       ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/my.url.log combined

    <Directory "/var/www/my.url">

        Options -Indexes
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/my.url/$1
    DirectoryIndex index.php

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue that you have is that you are trying to use two separate Apache modules in a way that the interaction is indeterminate. Use either ProxyPassMatch or RewriteRule, but not both.

Use either:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/public/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/public/$1
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/web/$1
```

Or use the `[P]` flag (proxy) within the Rewrite rules so that the execution ordering rules within `mod_rewrite` apply:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(?!public/).*$   web/$0 
RewriteRule ^.*\.php(/.*)?$   fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/$0 [P,END]
```

Note that `$0` is the entire match string.

In either of these, the rule precedence is well determined.